# how to convert perreplica to tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

When training with multi gpu in tensorflow2.0, perreplica would be reduce by below code:

```py
strategy.reduce(tf.distribute.ReduceOp.SUM, per_replica_losses, axis=None)
```

However, if I just want to collect(no 'sum reduce' or 'mean reduce') all gpu's predictions into a tensor:

```py
per_replica_losses, per_replica_predicitions = strategy.experimental_run_v2(train_step, args=(dataset_inputs,))
# how to convert per_replica_predicitions to a tensor ?
```

Answer (score 9):

In short, you can convert `PerReplica` result into a tuple of tensors like this:

```
tensors_tuple = per_replica_predicitions.values
```

the return `tensors_tuple` will be a tuple of `predictions` from each replicas/devices:

```
(predicton_tensor_from_dev0, prediction_tensor_from_dev1,...)
```

The number of elements in this tuple is determined by your devices available to the distributed strategy. Specially, if the strategy runs on a single replica/device, the return value from strategy.experimental_run_v2 will be the same as calling train_step function directly (tensor or list of tensors decided by your `train_step`). So you might want to write the code like this:

```
per_replica_losses, per_replica_predicitions = strategy.experimental_run_v2(train_step, args=(dataset_inputs,))

if strategy.num_replicas_in_sync > 1:
    predicition_tensors = per_replica_predicitions.values
else:
    predicition_tensors = per_replica_predicitions
```

`PerReplica` is a class object wrapping the results of distributed running. You can find its definition [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1cf0898dd4331baf93fe77205550f2c2e6c90ee5/tensorflow/python/distribute/values.py#L465), there are more properties/methods for us to operate the `PerReplica` object.